# GWT: Translate JSONValue into tree of Java POJOs

Tags: java, json, gwt

GWT provides a number of overlay types as wrappers to access complex JSON structures in a JavaScript environment, for instance [JSONValue](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONValue.html), [JSONArray](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONArray.html), [JSONNumber](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONNumber.html), etc.

However, these wrapper objects cannot be send back to the server through GWTs RPC mechanism, nor can they be serialized using Java Serialization or other serialization frameworks, since they only work on the client side (as overlay types).

Is there a library/framework available, which can translate a tree of generic JSONValues (of which the structure/type is not known) into a tree of serializalbe Java POJO objects such as:

```
class JJsonNumber implements Serializable, JJsonItem {
    double numberValue;
    ....
}

class JJsonObject implements Serializable, JJsonItem {
    Map<String, JJsonItem> properties;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) ?

Comment: I think Autobeans requires one to know the structure of the JSON data in advance (e.g. {"name": "Peter"} <=> class Person { String name; ...}). I would like to handle ANY JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

The reference implementation of JSON in Java should do the trick! (It's linked from the JSON.org website)

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

For instance:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

see [JSONObject.java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java)

However, in order for this JSON reference implementation to run in a GWT environment would require some manual clean up work in the library (remove references to InputStream etc).